# Storing a span value into a javascript variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to write javascript that will go through a span, grab its value, and store it in a variable that can be used to perform arithmetic.

```
<span id ="Weekly" class="ServerData" data-tag="WeeklyCarSales">**30**</span>
<span id ="Monthly" class="ServerData" data-tag="DailyCarSales">**6**</span>
```

Pertaining to the above two lines, my function is given below. In this current set up I get no result.

```
function divide(n1, n2) {
    ans = n1 / n2;
    document.write(" " + ans + "<BR>");
    return ans;
}
var a = $('#WeeklyCarSales').ServerData;
var b = $('#DailyCarSales').ServerData;
divide(a, b);
```

I should be getting an answer of "5" yet get nothing. I know the actual arithmetic works if I force an integer/float value into the variables. I seem to have continuous trouble locking down the the '30' and '6', which are the span values. Any ideas on how to grab those 2 span values?

Comment: Are the values in your spans actually surrounded with asterisks?

Comment: See the console and if you find any `division by zero`... oh sorry, `0/0` should be resulting `NaN` :P

Comment: It's because a) you're looking for ids `WeeklyCarSales` and `DailyCarSales`, but the spans have ids `Weekly` and `Monthly`, and b) `ServerData` is not a property of a jQuery object. Did you mean `$( '#Weekly' ).text()` and `$( '#Monthly' ).text()`? See http://jsfiddle.net/gdWta/

Comment: no they are not in asterisks I was trying to make them bold in the post (kinda new here, still learning the formatting)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This should do the trick...

```
function divide(n1, n2) {
    var ans = n1 / n2;
    document.write(" " + ans + "<BR>");
    return ans;
}

var a = parseInt($("#Weekly.ServerData").text().replace(/\*/gmi, ""), 10)
  , b = parseInt($("#Monthly.ServerData").text().replace(/\*/gmi, ""), 10);

divide(a, b);
```

​​Here is working [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dKXep/3/)

Comment: Extra semicolon is extra ;) . . (end of the var a declaration)

Comment: Probably you should use `.split('*').join('')` instead of `.replace("*", "")`

Comment: @VitaliyPetrychuk Changed the replace using a regex ;-) Created a working JSFiddle to verify it.

Comment: Excellent example. Thank you tremendously!

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
function divide(n1, n2) {
    ans = n1 / n2;
    document.write(" " + ans + "<BR>");
    return ans;
} 
var a  = $('#Weekly').html().replace('*','');
var b = $('#Monthly').html().replace('*','');
divide(a, b);
```

Answer (score 2):

There are a number of problems here.  First, in jQuery the ('#SOMETHING') construct references a DOM element by ID.  So, You would need to use $('#Weekly') and $('#Monthly') to reference the span elements.

Second, the ServerData class value that is applied to the tag is not an available property on the element so trying to reference $('#Monthly').ServerData isn't going to do anything for you.

What you are really looking for is the HTML contents of the node which you would access like this

```
var a = parseInt($('#Weekly').html());
```

I am not sure if those asterisks are actually there or not.  If they are truly there you need to remove them like this:

```
var a = parseInt($('#Weekly').html().replace('*', ''));
```

Comment: You've got a syntax error in your last line of code ($ and #).