# Issues with NaN as function result instead of necessary integer

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, casting

This post is a continuation of previous ones I have made regarding span values of JS.
In the lines below, when I open my Javascript console in Chrome, I see my values near the closing of the the  tags. Lets say they are 20 and 10 respectively. However those values are not in the actual html code (as depicted below). In my javascript function, I am simply trying to 'extract' the span values, divide them, and return a value. I keep getting 'NaN' as my result. Do I need to typecast something somewhere for the function to return a numeric value?

**Note: values are read in from a historian, 'PI'**

```
<span id ="LineSpeedGE" class='PIData' data-tag='G2LineSpeedGE'></span> (value of 20)

<span id ="AimPsSpd"    class='PIData' data-tag='G2rCurrentAimPsSpd'></span> (value of 10)
```

JS Function:

```
 function divide(n1,n2)
 { ans = n1/n2;
     document.write(" "+ans+"<BR>");    
     return ans;
 }

 var a = parseInt($("LineSpeedGE.PIData[data-tag]").data("tag"), 10);
 var b = parseInt($("AimPsSpd.PIData[data-tag]").data("tag"), 10);

divide (a, b);
```

I get NaN as a result instead of the expected '2'. If I plug in regular integers into the variables, the actual division is fine. I seem to have trouble 'capturing' the actual value of the span that not visible in my html code. I suspect data-types are clashing?

Here is the link to my original post: [Storing a span value into a javascript variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11690632/storing-a-span-value-into-a-javascript-variable) for reference if this seems convoluted.

Comment: the `data-tag` is not a parseable number.. also you are using wrong selectors

Comment: `G2LineSpeedGE` and `G2rCurrentAimPsSpd` aren't numbers.

Comment: Where are the actual values stored?  Your `data-tag` values obviously aren't numbers.

Comment: The numbers are being pulled in from a database by the tag name. The whole package is accompanied with quite a bit of CSS files so maybe somewhere in there is a way to get just the raw number.

Comment: What if I parsed for a string, then typecasted it into an Int?

Comment: @J.C.Morris: Where is the raw number in the HTML?  Is the `"(value of 20)"` part of the HTML?

Comment: @J.C.Morris: Parsed what for a string?  What does `G2LineSpeedGE` mean?

Answer (score 2):

`G2LineSpeedGE` is not a number, neither `G2rCurrentAimPsSpd` is.

`<span id ="LineSpeedGE" class='PIData' data-tag='42'></span>` will work.

Comment: This will not work since the selectors are wrong in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

First off, your selectors are wrong.

```
$("LineSpeedGE.PIData[data-tag]")
```

This looks for a element named `LineSpeedGE` (`<LineSpeedGE/>`).  You probably want:

```
$("#LineSpeedGE.PIData[data-tag]")
```

The `#` makes it search for ID (if you're searching by ID, the `.PIData[data-tag]` isn't necessary).

Also, the `data-tag` values aren't numbers.  They are `G2LineSpeedGE` and `G2rCurrentAimPsSpd`, those aren't numbers.

Answer (score 1):

Your selector is wrong so you are not getting any elements returned.

```
$("LineSpeedGE.PIData[data-tag]")
```

It is missing the `#`, so you are looking for an element named LineSpeedGE, not an id.

```
$("#LineSpeedGE.PIData[data-tag]")
```

Same thing applys to `AimPsSpd`. Missing the `#`

Also `G2LineSpeedGE` is a string, not a number so that will also result in NAN when parseInt is run.